# Why can't we differentiate one variable with respect to another variable?

Tags: derivatives

This sounds a little immature, but why can't we differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ ? Why does $y$ have to be written in terms of $x$ to differentiation?

Why cant $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3a^2$ where $y=a^3$ where $a$ is a variable?

Thank you.

Comment: If y = a^3, then you would write dy/da = 3a^2.

Comment: we can, but we use the chain rule... If $y=a^3$ then ${dy\over dx}={dy\over da}{da\over dx} = 3a^2{da\over dx} $

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, you can differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$. The result is $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$$ because of independency.

Comment: @Tom-Tom can you please explain how dy/dx = 0 because of independency? Thank you.

Comment: It the definition of independency itself. If $y$ does not depend on $x$, then it means that $y$ does not vary when $x$ varies.